# Ambiguity when a sentence contains multiple possessive pronouns

Tags: pronouns, possessives, ambiguity

I have a question related to [another one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17326/advice-for-using-multiple-same-gender-personal-pronouns-in-the-same-sentence) that I have asked.

In the following sentence, whose father is being referenced?

> Billy’s friend and his father were there.

In the following re-structured sentence, whose friend is being referenced?

> Billy’s father and his friend were there.

Clearly, there is ambiguity about the second (or subsequent) nouns. Is there a better way to structure such sentences to remove the ambiguity?

Answer (score 5):

There's always going to be some ambiguity, but I believe that

> Billy's friend and his father were there.

is talking about the *friend's* father; to refer instead to Billy's father, you'd need to remove the "his":

> Billy's friend and father were there.

Similarly for the other way around:

> Billy's father and his friend were there.

is probably talking about the father's friend, while

> Billy's father and friend were there.

is talking about Billy's friend.

To remove *all* ambiguity, you're gonna need to rewrite things.

> Billy's friend was there, and Billy's father arrived eventually, too.

Comment: I was thinking that *Billy’s friend and Billy’s father were there.* sounded too verbose. I suppose that removing the “his” could actually help. That’s not bad.

Comment: That's a good father who shows up late just to help his son be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Billy's friend and his friend's father were there.
The other possibility is a bit harder to rephrase concisely and unambiguously. Possibly something like: Billy's friend was there, as was Billy's father.